# phonenumber regular expression to fix the prefix

Tags: php, regex

Basically what I need to do is when I have a phonenumber like this one: `31655334868` I need to change  that to: `1655334868` (removed the first `3`)

But I can also have `0031655334868` and then I need to change that to: `1655334868`.

How can i do this in PHP with a regex? Or is there a better alternative way?

Comment: From your examples you can just `substr` off the last 10 characters.

Comment: @kolink Upvote for the simplest answer not most of us are geared to find :)

Comment: lol..nice answer...but no...i can have phonenumbers with 10 or 9 characters..yes the prefix is country dependent

Comment: `$phone = preg_replace("/^0*3?/", "", $phone);`?

Comment: Removing country codes? You know that there are codes with more than one digit? Or are you only removing the `3`? "like this one" is a very broad definition, and here it's not clear what you want in other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with regex then you could use the following code:

(this also takes into account that you could have a number starting with `+31`)

```
$phone1 = '31655334868';
$phone2 = '0031655334868';
$phone3 = '+31655334868';

if ( preg_match ( '/^.*3([0-9]{10})$/', $phone2, $matches ) )
{
    print_r($matches);
    echo $matches[1]; // will always contain the desired result
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Working example:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/FAuh2c

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($phoneNumber, -10);
```

Comment: Returns `3165533486` for the first example and `0031655334` for the second. Did you bother thinking?